# Counting points on Elliptic Curves with CM by $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-d}]$, $d=1,3$ (CM ring with non-trivial units)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

Consider an elliptic curve $E/H$ with CM by the entire ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ of $K=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-d}]$ (and such that $j(E)=j(\mathcal{O}_K)$) such that $H$ is the Hilbert class field of $K$. Consider a prime $\mathfrak{B}\nmid 2$ of $H$ such that $E$ has good reduction at $\mathfrak{B}$.

A paper by [Rubin and Silverberg](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272482/1-s2.0-S0022314X09X00119/1-s2.0-S0022314X09000663/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEI3%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJGMEQCIBrUnBPGo%2BWWQcPnVotYNMWTnlYYPbfFk1orkekbqAxdAiBNYBAe4Busknnu%2F7hpEeOmSqU1CWabnKpyBUE4VvElJirbBAiV%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F8BEAQaDDA1OTAwMzU0Njg2NSIMrFLVWWDUgYsOFgEQKq8ETKzbtCALOFR6bnil3VQ5vKUrOhDpYe6bBFj0ws2yfYkYQ9S68kDeFun6ENcCLEGBEl2AiGwq%2BNIVC6t4q8MyJSERuEysaWyO3r6%2Ff6FvtjEHEo4FClKtwyXy2Ufgg2bUlQQe4Ti8ZO99dcqNwPc5Ic0ueBwt1wNrVezqYzfOZCkfieHFEV4VEYj1edaUMZKljb9UtFo7sboG4LwX4U8FyZy%2B3HggXY72zafpbw4nWbBcZJfVXBCIplgEcuGLqLe4afWtfxdCCct3UZcTPP0A6YAJclJotdHCofskljaAGzDinVSftfQqMZVZiBZBYbHCwp6c%2BDMhyw%2BlKqZZQL%2BAuiYDs9bjzvUqbVjatABNb2BghOhs37eU%2FH9DN2TZQIxBy1BDV0S83nmLUFM%2FQyOyW8%2BRZjc2Ct3xumTy1PfQj%2FrhTF3cTrf%2B0lmSwJ67E5mH5V%2F4q9217hzcNvELs5MoBKbTL0MicCXNHuAlXBcHUegGBHfcjxTJ0tzHjdjd%2F3qZRJUrx8ZSws5h6Oy4upW0BQRRG2qX11gWKwiQIpRkoiI%2BWojJYUqC7L6rYLyeKnrJgZ7NYy%2FYxHbDe0%2BSSSE43ZH4v%2Fvd8iQGxWK%2BOU7REKKqLJuZMkXKTxUS8wd9t1mYT7%2B55qxhA3MtIGvs53%2FLWzlF2mQcIKVcodXnecJQuXLQZWQS6P9VJ4PDLt7B55zLTqZN7sk7GrW9N%2BJHa1x2HOchf29qa8GX7R%2Bn7oXP4TCc1qOVBjqqAWvoSYibeO0WFcjisc3IdwiHV06Gm5G%2F%2BJCZR%2BP8QbJcfwJfz8XjSjlqc6pdCkLzsrZjNchd4Q5%2FGhZh530R56k%2F635lrgOU%2F5TnYLR6lN3fNrVqI4dn3z0jFWoSsTi91vJP6koMm2Lzk7DgIvscZh57e%2BzkiGI4aZqknTEjsaZn5nujf8YXQd15LAQixGxTbQ%2BEorndJUUghB2lTsX1krdsErstbQ4diniE&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20220614T212621Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYWKKPG2OC%2F20220614%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=d5e417510625189cb443569a6b9798c03a1a6d8d9edf9da8f2e336dde585cad3&hash=bebde9051c7a97b3d9ae5b06f6347b8ca005af24210ba2690e9422541e7a12b9&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0022314X09000663&tid=spdf-6f5ba83e-6f6d-4d51-8994-aa44a84caf20&sid=48cef9475984b747eb1b21a0f82ef9d2f099gxrqa&type=client&ua=515102575c5207035f07&rr=71b624ce9a0c9658) and a paper by [Stark](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/rocky-mountain-journal-of-mathematics/volume-26/issue-3/Counting-Points-on-CM-Elliptic-Curves/10.1216/rmjm/1181072041.pdf) provide a method to count the number of points on $E(\mathcal{O}_H/\mathfrak{B})$ by finding the Hecke character $\Psi(\mathfrak{B})$, provided that $d\neq 1,3$ and $d$ is squarefree (and $d>0$).

The squarefree assumption seems trivial, but the assumption $d\neq 1,3$ ensures that there are no non-trivial units in $\mathcal{O}_K$ so that $\Psi(\mathfrak{B})=\pm \operatorname{Norm}_{H/K} (\mathfrak{B})$. That is, we only have to consider $\pm$ and no other units.

**Question:** Are there any references/methods to count the number of points on $E(\mathcal{O}_H/\mathfrak{B})$ for $E/H$ with CM by $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-1}]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-3}]$? That is, for CM by fields whose rings of integers have non-trivial units.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4472831/counting-points-on-elliptic-curves-with-cm-by-mathbbq-sqrt-d-d-1-3

Comment: This is crossposted from the above link